# ¿No me carga los input de una clase?

Tags: poo, clase, python-3.7, input

**Estoy utilizando python 3.7**

*Estoy Aprendiendo programación*

**Tengo la clase empleado:**

```
    #Creación de Clase
class empleado: #se crea la clase empleado
    def _init_(self):
        self._nombretrab=""
        self._horastrab=0
        self._cuotahora=0
        self._sueldo=0
    def establecernombreemp(self,nombreT):
            self._nombretrab=nombreT
    def establecerhorastrab(self,horaT):
            self._horastrab=horaT
    def establecercuotahora(self, cuotaH):
            self._cuotahora=cuotaH
    def calcularsueldo(self):
            sueldo=self._cuotahora*self._horastrab
            if self._horastrab<40: #estas líneas se agregaron después en clases y condicionesnes
                return sueldo
            else:
                    sueldo=sueldo*1.05
                    return sueldo         
    def obtenernombreemp(self):
            return self._nombretrab
```

Hecho con un if me permite aumentar el 5% del salario de un empleado si sus horas trabajadas son 40 horas o más hasta aquí todo bien. ya que puedo crear empleados por medio de esta clase y me calcula el sueldo sin problemas.

El verdadero problema es que al crear un algoritmo que procesa varios empleados, el mismo no me deja guardar en la variable "desea" cuando lo hago en el idle de python con otra clase llamada ejecutarempleado:

El cual debería elaborar un arlgoritmo que permita procesar varios empleados, teniendo como base la clase empleado  por cada empleado se leen los datos nombre del empleado, cuota de horas y horas trabajadas así como mostrar y calcular el sueldo.

```
class ejecutarempleado:
    def _init_(self):
            self._nomemp=""
            self._hrstra=0
            self._cuohr=0
            self._desea='' #almacena el valor de la pregunta variable booleana
            desea= input('¿Desea procesar empleado (S/N) ? ')
            while desea== 'S':
                _nomemp= input('Digite el nombre del empleado ')
                _hrstra= input('Digite el numero de horas de trabajo')
                _cuohr= input('Digite cuota de hora ')
                objempleado= empleado()
                objempleado.establecernombreemp(_nomemp)
                objempleado.establecerhorastrab(_hrstra)
                objempleado.esttablecercuotahora(_cuohr)
                print(objempleado.calcularsueldo())
                print(objempleado.obtenernombreemp())
                desea= input('¿Desea procesar empleado (S/N) ? ')
```

El problema es que no me muestra ningún error, pero tampoco me muestra los input necesarios para empezar a llenar los datos, no sé si estoy haciendo algo mal, ya que al cargar el código literalmente no pasa nada y no puedo seguir llenando empleados porque ni siquiera aparece la pregunta inicial cuya respuesta debería de guardarse en la variable "desea" y solo cuando "desea== 'S'" entonces puedo llenar los datos según el while mostrado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios errores.
**Primero**, El método constructor en python no es `_init_(self)`. Tiene que llevar dos guiones bajos seguidos al principio y al final: `__init__(self)`. Corregirlo en ambas clases.

**Segundo**, en la segunda clase, la línea

```
objempleado.esttablecercuotahora(_cuohr)
```

llama a un método que no existe en la primera clase, supongo que un error ortográfico, ya que debería ser

```
objempleado.establecercuotahora(_cuohr)
```

**Tercero**, En la primera clase, las líneas

```
def calcularsueldo(self):
    sueldo = self._cuotahora * self._horastrab
    if self._horastrab<40: #estas líneas se agregaron después en clases y condicionesnes
        return sueldo
    else:
        sueldo=sueldo*1.05
        return sueldo
```

arrojarán un error, porque estás multiplicando `string * string` y haciendo comparaciones en el `if` entre `strings` y `enteros`. Recuerda que los `input` reciben `strings` y tu tienes que convertirlos internamente. Se puede solucionar de varias formas; una que se me ocurre puede ser, en la segunda clase, hacer los llamados así:

```
objempleado.establecerhorastrab(int(_hrstra))
objempleado.establecercuotahora(float(_cuohr))
```

**[EDITADO]** 
Esto es para probar el funcionamiento de las dos clases, ya depende de tu lógica como instancies tus clases. Solo lo pongo como referencia.

```
class empleado: #se crea la clase empleado
    def __init__(self):
        self._nombretrab=""
        self._horastrab=0
        self._cuotahora=0
        self._sueldo=0
    def establecernombreemp(self,nombreT):
        self._nombretrab=nombreT
    def establecerhorastrab(self,horaT):
        self._horastrab=horaT
    def establecercuotahora(self, cuotaH):
        self._cuotahora=cuotaH
    def calcularsueldo(self):
        sueldo = self._cuotahora * self._horastrab
        if self._horastrab<40: #estas líneas se agregaron después en clases y condicionesnes
            return sueldo
        else:
            sueldo=sueldo*1.05
            return sueldo
    def obtenernombreemp(self):
        return self._nombretrab

class ejecutarempleado:
    def __init__(self):
        self._nomemp=""
        self._hrstra=0
        self._cuohr=0
        self._desea='' #almacena el valor de la pregunta variable booleana
        desea= input('¿Desea procesar empleado (S/N) ? ')
        while desea.upper() == 'S':
            _nomemp= input('Digite el nombre del empleado ')
            _hrstra= input('Digite el numero de horas de trabajo ')
            _cuohr= input('Digite cuota de hora ')
            objempleado= empleado()
            objempleado.establecernombreemp(_nomemp)
            objempleado.establecerhorastrab(int(_hrstra))
            objempleado.establecercuotahora(float(_cuohr))
            print(objempleado.calcularsueldo())
            print(objempleado.obtenernombreemp())
            desea= input('¿Desea procesar empleado (S/N) ? ')

ejecutarempleado()
```

La última linea ejecutará automáticamente el método `__init__()` de la clase ejecutarempleado, y como mencioné, es solo para la prueba, *"instanciando"* de forma directa segunda clase.

Comment: Por supuesto hice la correciones que mencionaste y me sirvió mucho y tiene sentido lo que decís sin embargo al ejecutar no aparecen los inputs. Ya lo intente ejecutar con geany y no me muestra errores solo lo ejecuta pero no me pregunta si deseo operar empleado, osea que sigo teniendo el mismo problema o las variables como self._horastrab también llevan doble guión?

Comment: El problema principal es que no lee el input de la variable desea.

Comment: @AdonizGómez Hice exactamente las mismas correcciones y si funcionó. ¿Estás llamando a la segunda clase de manera correcta?. Edité la respuesta y puse el código de la prueba que hice acá.

Comment: Gracias men ya  lo resolví simplemente era algo tan fácil como: ejecutarempleado() solo eso me faltaba, disculpa las molestias es que estoy aprendiendo poco a poco.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con:

```
while True: 
       if desea== 'S':
                _nomemp= input('Digite el nombre del empleado ')
                _hrstra= input('Digite el numero de horas de trabajo')
                _cuohr= input('Digite cuota de hora ')
                objempleado= empleado()
                objempleado.establecernombreemp(_nomemp)
                objempleado.establecerhorastrab(_hrstra)
                objempleado.esttablecercuotahora(_cuohr)
                print(objempleado.calcularsueldo())
                print(objempleado.obtenernombreemp())
                desea= input('¿Desea procesar empleado (S/N) ? ')
```

Comment: Intenté realizarlo de esa forma y aunque no me da error no se puede visualizar la pregunta al igual que el caso anterior.